# problems filtering out exceptions, that shouldnt be send as error mail

Tags: serilog

I'm using serilog and I have a problem regarding filtering out specific exceptions.

Following is not working, because it shouldn't send error mails when dubletExceptions or a ItemException occurs in code.

```
.WriteTo.Logger(l => l.Filter.ByExcluding(logEvent => (logEvent?.Exception is DubletException))
                                      .Filter.ByExcluding(logEvent => (logEvent?.Exception is ItemException))
                                      .WriteTo.Email(
                                        fromEmail: mailconfig.From,
                                        toEmail: "test@test.org",
                                        mailServer: mailconfig.SmtpServer,
                                        mailSubject: "error happened!",
                                        outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                                        restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Error));
```

filter part is:

```
.Filter.ByExcluding(logEvent => (logEvent?.Exception is ItemException))
```